# NAudio: Move Session Between Devices

Tags: .net, naudio

I have several sound cards on my PC. Using NAudio and c#/vb is it possible to direct a given AudioSessionControl to a known Device? If not is there any other way of controlling what sound card a program gets outputted to?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**
So on further research it seems that was the wrong approach... I have however discovered I can play the same mp3 file on two separate cards like this:

```
        Dim WaveOut = New WaveOut() ' Or WaveOutEvent()
        WaveOut.DeviceNumber = 1
        WaveOut.Init(input1)
        WaveOut.Play()


        Dim WaveOut2 = New WaveOut() ' Or WaveOutEvent()
        WaveOut2.DeviceNumber = 2
        WaveOut2.Init(input1)
        WaveOut2.Play()
```

But it causes a great deal of stuttering. Does anyone know if I can play them in sync?

I've also been reading some of Marks blogs, especially [this one](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/handling-multi-channel-audio-in-naudio.html). It's possible to have quite a lot of flexability if your single sound card has several output channels. I wonder if it'd be possible to have several sound cards appear to be multiple output channels of a single card?